# Changing CSS Variable via JS

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, dom-events, css-variables

I'm trying to change the values of a Keyframe through a Click Event.

What I currently have is the following code:

```
:root {
  --background-positionI: 0;
}
body{
  --background-positionF: 0;
}

.firstPanel-R{
    animation: animatedBackground 3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% { 
      background-position: var(--background-positionI), 0;
    }
    100% { 
      background-position: var(--background-positionF), 0;
    }
}
```

I'm setting the variable at Root and Body and then I'm trying to change them via the next clickEvent:

```
arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function(){
    ++clickTargetCounter;

    backgroundImg.classList.add("firstPanel-R");

    finalPositionBackground = clickTargetCounter * -2037;
    initialPositionBackground = finalPositionBackground - -2037 + 'px';

    root.style.setProperty("--background-positionF", clickTargetCounter * -2037 + 'px', 0)
    body.style.setProperty("--background-positionI", finalPositionBackground - -2037 + 'px', 0)
});
```

For some reason the CSS variables stay at 0 and don't update to the values set in the click event.

Comment: you should move the `'` after the `px` to after the `0` --> `clickTargetCounter * -2037 + 'px, 0'`

Comment: Oh what a dumbass I am, but now the variable updates but the Keyframe doesn't

Comment: remove `,`: background-position don't need comma bettwen values